# Django annotate value based on another model field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have these two models, Cases and Specialties, just like this:

```
class Case(models.Model):
   ...
   judge = models.CharField()
   ....

class Specialty(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   sys_num = models.IntegerField()
```

I know this sounds like a really weird structure but try to bare with me:
The field `judge` in the `Case` model refer to a `Specialty` instance `sys_num` value (`judge` is a charfield but it will always carries an integer) (each `Specialty` instance has a unique `sys_num`). So I can get the `Specialty` name related to a specific `Case` instance using something like this:

```py
my_pk = #some number here...
my_case_judge = Case.objects.get(pk=my_pk).judge
my_specialty_name = Specialty.objects.get(sys_num=my_case_judge)
```

I know this sounds really weird but I can't change the underlying schemma of the tables, just work around it with sql and Django's orm.

My problem is: I want to annotate the `Specialty` names in a queryset of `Cases` that have already called `values()`.

I only managed to get it working using `Case` and `When` but it's not dynamic. If I add more `Specialty` instances I'll have to manually alter the code.

```py
 cases.annotate(
         specialty=Case(
             When(judge=0, then=Value('name 0 goes here')),
             When(judge=1, then=Value('name 1 goes here')),
             When(judge=2, then=Value('name 2 goes here')),
             When(judge=3, then=Value('name 3 goes here')),
             ...
```

Can this be done dynamically? I look trough [django's query reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/) docs but couldn't produce a working solution with the tools specified there.

Comment: Please then you should use a `ForeignKey` to the `speciality`, this is really "ugly" modeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a [*subquery expression*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Case.objects.annotate(
    specialty=Subquery(
        Specialty.objects.filter(sys_num=OuterRef('judge')).values('name')[:1]
    )
)
```

For some databases, casting might even be necessary:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, OuterRef, Subquery
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

Case.objects.annotate(
    specialty=Subquery(
        Specialty.objects.filter(sys_num=Cast(
            OuterRef('judge'),
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )).values('name')[:1]
    )
)
```

But the modeling is *very* bad. Usually it is better to work with a `ForeignKey`, this will guarantee that the `judge` can only point to a valid case (so referential integrity), will create indexes on the fields, and it will also make the Django ORM more effective since it allows more advanced querying with (relativily) small queries.

Comment: wow, this works! I'm seriously surprised. Thank you very very much :))